# Symfony2 FosUserBundle is not hydrating User Entity with custom Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have my own User Entity which extends the Fos one. It is capable of having another Entity attached to it as a manyToOne relationship.

Using the following code inside my own Profile Controller results in this Entity not being added to the User Entity.

```
$user = $repo->find($user->getId());
```

All my other custom fields are in place, its just this Entity that is missing. The relationship looks like this

```
manyToOne:
    game_system:
        targetEntity: Acme\NameofBundle\Entity\GameSystem
        joinColumn:
            onDelete: SET NULL
            name: game_system_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**Edit**

It's worth noting that the getGameSystem call works inside my main Bundle, NameofBundle.

But it fails inside of MemberBundle, MemberBundle extends FOSUserBundle. The GameSystem Entity is inside NameofBundle while my User is my MemberBundle.

**Edit 2**

My config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\MemberBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: Acme\MemberBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: how you set the relation ?

Comment: The YML is already in the question?

Comment: thats the mapping yes but where do you setGameSystem() ?

Comment: It's already set and is in the DB. If I make the same call in my own controller it's fine. It only fails in my FOS controller

Comment: @johnSmith see my edit about how my bundles are split

Comment: Do you have the `user_class` property set in `config.yml` ?

Comment: Yes, see my new update

Comment: Does your **MemberBundle** has a getParent() function that returns `'FOSUserBundle'` ?

Comment: I sure have. The bundle works correctly apart from on this example.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the line:

```
$user = $repo->find($user->getId());
```

which seems redundant
How can you id from user if you haven't fetched user from database yet?
or, if you have already user object you don't need to get it from database.
The following would be more correct and to get the id you want you'd have to make a list with findAll().

```
$user = $repo->find($id);
```